# How to find next element that matches a previous element within a tolerance in a list of lists?

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

i have big list of sorted sublists containing lists like below:

```
biglist = [  
[[25368, 22348], [22348, 21234], [21230, 17750], [17754, 15924], [15924, 14490],[14491, 12780]]   
[[22390, 21242], [10140, 4260], [4260, 2686], [2686, 438]],  
[[14044, 8726], [8762, 4144], [4144, 1420]],  
[[5817, 5097], [5590, 5530], [5304, 2729], [5097, 4430], [3450, 2489], [2729, 1676] , [2489, 1618]]  
]
```

for each sublist - ideally,

```py
for sublist in biglist:
    for i, element in enumerate(sublist):
         abs(element[i][1] - element [i+1][0]) < 10
```

for instance, sublist `[[25368, 22348], [22348, 21234], [21230, 17750], [17754, 15924], [15924, 14490], [14491, 12780]` doesn't have any issue because:

```
22348 - 22348 = 0  
21234 - 21230 = 4
17750 - 17754 = 4
15924 - 15924 = 0 
14490 - 14491 = 1
```

so, if the above condition (abs(element[i][1] - element [i+1][0]) < 10) is not satisfied what i want to do is find the next match of element[i][1] within the list that satisfies the above condition - print out the matching element then print out the skipped elements:

for example, in sublist

```
[[5817, 5097], [5590, 5530], [5304, 2729], [5094, 4430], [3450, 2489], [2729, 1676], [2489, 1618]]
```

code should print something like this:

```
[5817,5097] matches [5094, 4430] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements: [5590, 5530], [5304, 2729]
[5304, 2729] matches [2729, 1676] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements: [5094, 4430], [3450, 2489]
[3450, 2489] matches [2489, 1618] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements: [2729, 1676]
```

and if no match is found at all, print:
`[5590, 5530] has no match`

ANSWER:

i seem to be getting my desired results using:

```py
for sublist in biglist:
    for i, element in list(enumerate(sublist))[:-1]:
        found = False
        if abs(sublist[i][1] - sublist[i+1][0]) > 10:
            for j in range(i+1, len(sublist)):
                if abs(sublist[i][1] - sublist[j][0]) < 10:
                    print(sublist[i], "matches",  sublist[j], "within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements:", sublist[i+1:j])
                    found = True
                    break
            if not found:
                print(sublist[i], "has no matches")
```

but `has no matches` is giving me the wrong result:

```
[22390, 21242] has no matches
[14044, 8726] has no matches
[5817, 5097] matches [5097, 4430] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements: [[5590, 5530] [5304, 2729]]
[5590, 5530] has no matches
[5304, 2729] matches [2729, 1676] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements: [[5097, 4430], [3450, 2489]]
[5097, 4430] has no matches
[3450, 2489] matches [2489, 1618] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements: [[2729, 1676]]
[2729, 1676] has no matches
```

Comment: You can possibly speed this up with `scipy.spatial.KDTree`, just as an FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it, just create a new loop inside with `j` that starts at `i`, checks for a match along the way and ends when the first match is found.

```
biglist = [
    [[25368, 22348], [22348, 21234], [21234, 17750], [17750, 15924], [15924, 14490], [14490, 12780], [12780, 9418], [9418, 7460], [7460, 4884], [4884, 4340]], 
    [[22390, 21242], [10140, 4260], [4260, 2686], [2686, 438]], 
    [[14044, 8726], [8762, 4144], [4144, 1420]], [[5817, 5097], [5590, 5530], [5304, 2729], [5097, 4430], [3450, 2489], [2729, 1676] , [2489, 1618]]
]

for sublist in biglist:
  matched = set()
  for i, element in list(enumerate(sublist))[:-1]:
    found = False
    for j in range(i+1, len(sublist)):
      if abs(sublist[i][1] - sublist[j][0]) < 10:
        print(sublist[i], "matches",  sublist[j], "within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements", sublist[i+1:j])
        matched.add(tuple(sublist[j]))
        found = True
        break
    if not found and tuple(sublist[i]) not in matched:
      print(sublist[i], "has no matches")
```

*Result*

```
[25368, 22348] matches [22348, 21234] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements []
[22348, 21234] matches [21234, 17750] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements []
[21234, 17750] matches [17750, 15924] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements []
[17750, 15924] matches [15924, 14490] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements []
[15924, 14490] matches [14490, 12780] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements []
[14490, 12780] matches [12780, 9418] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements []
[12780, 9418] matches [9418, 7460] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements []
[9418, 7460] matches [7460, 4884] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements []
[7460, 4884] matches [4884, 4340] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements []
[22390, 21242] has no matches
[10140, 4260] matches [4260, 2686] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements []
[4260, 2686] matches [2686, 438] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements []
[14044, 8726] has no matches
[8762, 4144] matches [4144, 1420] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements []
[5817, 5097] matches [5097, 4430] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements [[5590, 5530], [5304, 2729]]
[5590, 5530] has no matches
[5304, 2729] matches [2729, 1676] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements [[5097, 4430], [3450, 2489]]
[3450, 2489] matches [2489, 1618] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements [[2729, 1676]]
```

Comment: thanks for answering! :) would you be able to also see what's wrong here? thanks u so much :))) https://stackoverflow.com/a/56919133/11749148

Answer (score 0):

@fizzybear thanks for answering :)

i seem to be getting my desired results using:

```py
for sublist in biglist:
    for i, element in list(enumerate(sublist))[:-1]:
        found = False
        if abs(sublist[i][1] - sublist[i+1][0]) > 10:
            for j in range(i+1, len(sublist)):
                if abs(sublist[i][1] - sublist[j][0]) < 10:
                    print(sublist[i], "matches",  sublist[j], "within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements:", sublist[i+1:j])
                    found = True
                    break
            if not found:
                print(sublist[i], "has no matches")
```

but `has no matches` is giving me the wrong result:

```
[22390, 21242] has no matches
[14044, 8726] has no matches
[5817, 5097] matches [5097, 4430] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements: [[5590, 5530] [5304, 2729]]
[5590, 5530] has no matches
[5304, 2729] matches [2729, 1676] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements: [[5097, 4430], [3450, 2489]]
[5097, 4430] has no matches
[3450, 2489] matches [2489, 1618] within tolerance of 10 - skipped elements: [[2729, 1676]]
[2729, 1676] has no matches
```

Comment: You should comment on the older posts instead of creating a new answer. Code can go in a pastebin.  The indent for `if not found` is off by one.

Comment: @fizzybear thanks for pointing that out :)  i'm a newbie to stackoverflow as well as python. moving the ```if not found``` statement is still giving me the wrong results.

Comment: You're checking for `abs(...)` twice. You only need the inner one since `j` starts at `i+1`.

Comment: thank u for replying actively :)  i added the outer if statement ```if abs(sublist[i][1] - sublist[i+1][0]) > 10``` because i only want to print out elements that satisfies this condition first. also, removing the outer if statement still gives me invalid results:

these two should not be printed: 
```'[2729, 1676] has no matches' - because [5304, 2729] matches [2729, 1676]  
  ```   and 
```'[5097, 4430] has no matches' - because [5817, 5097] matches [5097, 4430]
```

Comment: I see. The matching goes backwards as well. Check the edited answer.

Comment: That did it!! Thaaaanks a lot for answering all my questions. Have a good day, dear! :)))